# Azure Event Hubs >20 Subscribing Applications

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

According to [Azure's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas), Event Hubs are limited to 20 Consumer Groups.

I have a use case where I would like to broadcast an event to 50+ different 3rd party service. I have a processor for each, which combines the event with some other state, translate and send it out.

It is the same event received by all consumers so I do not think partitioning is relevant here.

How do I implement a large number of consuming services with Event Hubs? Am I doing it wrong? Is this a limitation of the way the Event Hubs client works?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider implementing a **Pub-Sub** mechanism using **[Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/)**, whether it's instead of the **Events Hub** or "after" it. It will allow to publish the event to all subscribed 3rd party services.

Take a look at [Get started with Service Bus topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) on how this might be implemented.

Hope it helps!